# Using device name instead of ID in OpenCV method VideoCapture.open()

Tags: c++, opencv, video, camera, video-capture

I have a lot of video devices in my `/dev` folder (e.g. `video1`, `video2`, ..., `video9`) and one `/dev/video` which is always pointing to the valid device (which, of course, can change).
I want to open the `/dev/video` device with OpenCV using `cv::Videocapture` and realized that there are only two ways to open it:

```
VideoCapture::VideoCapture(const string& filename)
VideoCapture::VideoCapture(int device)
```

The first one opens a file and the second one opens `/dev/video[device]`.

Is there any way to do something like `cap = cv::VideoCapture("/dev/video");`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with current OpenCV 3.2.0 you can create a new capture like this:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap("/dev/video20", cv::CAP_V4L);
```

its one of the additional constructors:

> [VideoCapture (const String &filename, int apiPreference)](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a85b55cf6a4a50451367ba96b65218ba1)
>   Open video file or a capturing device or a IP video stream for video capturing with API Preference.

this is also possible with the open function:

```
cap.open("/dev/video20", cv::CAP_V4L);
```

i have tested this successfully under Kubuntu 16.10 with self compiled openCV from current git master.

Comment: I am having the same issue, Any solution for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the source code of OpenCV 2.4.11 (cap.cpp) you can see that the overload using const string& filename is calling 'cvCreateFileCapture' which uses other plugins as FFMPEG or GStreamer to load files so the answer is no.

```
bool VideoCapture::open(const string& filename)
{
   if (isOpened()) release();
   cap = cvCreateFileCapture(filename.c_str());
   return isOpened();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to parse the ID of the device.

```
#include <regex>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

...

boost::filesystem::path path( "/dev/video3" );
auto target = boost::filesystem::canonical(path).string();
std::regex exp( ".*video(\\d+)" );
std::smatch match;
std::regex_search( target, match, exp );
auto id = strtod( match[1] );
auto cap = cv::VideoCapture( id );
```

Note the use of `canonical()` to make the path absolute and resolve any symbolic links. This way it works even if you give it v4l device paths from `/dev/v4l/by-id` or `/dev/v4l/by-path` like for example:

```
"/dev/v4l/by-id/usb-046d_0990_1188AD49-video-index0"
"/dev/v4l/by-path/pci-0000:00:13.2-usb-0:4.4.4:1.0-video-index0"
```