# How can I use OpenCV to capture video stream of ueye cameras?

Tags: opencv, ueye

I'm used to work with logitech cameras in OpenCV. Appearently, VideoCapture(*) function takes as argument the number of the camera device in /dev/video*. However, when using Ueye cameras, the entry for the device is /dev/ueye and not /dev/video* .
Is there an easy way to retrieve the video stream from ueye cameras? Preferably keeping VideoCapture function.

Comment: You could look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42416185/5994091). You can try `VideoCapture("/dev/ueye")` and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you just Need to call the capture with an id like 0.

`VideoCapture(0)` works for me on Linux and Windows