# Can not grab image from VideoCapture OpenCV with Asus Xtion Pro Live

Tags: c++, opencv, openni, primesense

I just installed `OpenCV 2.4.7` with `OpenNI` and primesense Sensor as it can be seen in the following build information.

I have problems grabbing from a `VideoCapture` object. For instance, if I run the openni_capture example, I get "Can not grab images." but I get info about the depth and RGB cameras, so I think I'm getting the `VideoCapture` object properly opened, but by the time it tries to grab an image, the grab function returns 0.

I am using an Asus Xtion Pro Live and OpenNI and Sensor are working properly since I am able to run examples such as NiViewer.

I would appreciate some help with this problem.

Thank you!

```
General configuration for OpenCV 2.4.7 =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Platform:
    Host:                        Linux 3.5.0-47-generic x86_64
    CMake:                       2.8.9
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
    Configuration:               Release

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 4.7.2)
    C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -ffunction-sections -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -ffunction-sections -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG -ggdb3
    C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/gcc
    C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -ffunction-sections -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -ffunction-sections -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG -ggdb3
    Linker flags (Release):      
    Linker flags (Debug):        
    Precompiled headers:         YES

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 core flann imgproc highgui features2d calib3d ml video legacy objdetect photo gpu ocl nonfree contrib java python stitching superres ts videostab
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 androidcamera

  GUI: 
    QT:                          NO
    GTK+ 2.x:                    YES (ver 2.24.13)
    GThread :                    YES (ver 2.34.1)
    GtkGlExt:                    NO
    OpenGL support:              NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.7)
    JPEG:                        libjpeg (ver 62)
    PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.2.49)
    TIFF:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
    JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)

  Video I/O:
    DC1394 1.x:                  NO
    DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.0)
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      codec:                     YES (ver 53.35.0)
      format:                    YES (ver 53.21.1)
      util:                      YES (ver 51.22.2)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 2.1.0)
      gentoo-style:              YES
    GStreamer:                   
      base:                      YES (ver 0.10.36)
      app:                       YES (ver 0.10.36)
      video:                     YES (ver 0.10.36)
    OpenNI:                      YES (ver 1.5.7, build 10)
    OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  YES (/usr/lib/libXnCore.so)
    PvAPI:                       NO
    GigEVisionSDK:               NO
    UniCap:                      NO
    UniCap ucil:                 NO
    V4L/V4L2:                    Using libv4l (ver 0.8.8)
    XIMEA:                       NO
    Xine:                        NO

  Other third-party libraries:
    Use IPP:                     NO
    Use Eigen:                   YES (ver 3.0.93)
    Use TBB:                     NO
    Use OpenMP:                  NO
    Use GCD                      NO
    Use Concurrency              NO
    Use C=:                      NO
    Use Cuda:                    NO
    Use OpenCL:                  YES

  OpenCL:
    Version:                     dynamic
    Include path:                /home/xxx/imageproc/opencv-2.4.7/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Use AMD FFT:                 NO
    Use AMD BLAS:                NO

  Python:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2 (ver 2.7.3)
    Libraries:                   /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.3)
    numpy:                       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.6.2)
    packages path:               lib/python2.7/dist-packages

  Java:
    ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.8.2)
    JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/include /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/include /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/include
    Java tests:                  YES

  Documentation:
    Build Documentation:         NO
    Sphinx:                      NO
    PdfLaTeX compiler:           /usr/bin/pdflatex

  Tests and samples:
    Tests:                       YES
    Performance tests:           YES
    C/C++ Examples:              YES

  Install path:                  /usr/local

  cvconfig.h is in:              /home/xxx/imageproc/opencv-2.4.7/release
```

I instantiate the videocapture and try to grab an image as follows:

```
VideoCapture capture;

capture.open(CV_CAP_OPENNI);

if ( !capture.isOpened() )
{
    cout << "Error opening capture" << endl;
    return -1;
}


if( !capture.grab() )
{
    cout << "Can not grab image" << endl;
}
```

Comment: can you post a snippet of how you instantiate the video capture ?

Comment: Edited! Hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code my guess is that will use the kinect openni driver as opposed to the asus openni driver

How about this:

```
VideoCapture capture;

capture.open(CV_CAP_OPENNI_ASUS);

if ( !capture.isOpened() )
{
    cout << "Error opening capture" << endl;
    return -1;
}


if( !capture.grab() )
{
    cout << "Can not grab image" << endl;
}
```

I have managed to use two asus xtion pro sensors with opencv in the past, you can see my test [code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983248/how-to-initialize-multiple-openni-sensors-with-opencv/15001116#15001116).

Also, these are the values from the [highui types header](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/ccbceb56c488892f5d0f0a384750028a11082af7/modules/highgui/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h#L310), with comments:

```
CV_CAP_OPENNI   =900,   // OpenNI (for Kinect)
CV_CAP_OPENNI_ASUS =910,   // OpenNI (for Asus Xtion)
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I will change that once I get home. Anyways, I had a previous install and I tried the [openni_capture](https://github.com/alexmac/alcexamples/blob/master/OpenCV-2.4.2/samples/cpp/openni_capture.cpp) example, and it uses the constant CV_CAP_OPENNI in the main function for opening the VideoCapture, and after that uses different constants depending on which camera you are using.

I'll let you know if it works once I try it! Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to mention that in the previous install the openni_capture worked with the ASUS :)

Comment: glad that worked! feel free to vote/mark this question if you found it helpful ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I just checked it and it works. I don't know why but in another project it worked with the constant CV_CAP_OPENNI using the Asus. I think I was using OpenCV 2.4.6, I don't know if it has been a change in the 2.4.7 version.

Anyway, it worked! Thanks!