# Cannot capture video from ASUS Xtion using OpenCV on Jetson TK1

Tags: opencv, openni, asus-xtion

I'm having trouble capturing video from an ASUS Xtion on an Nvidia Jetson TK1 using OpenCV (also on a laptop -- see update below). When I run the following code, I always get "Error."

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  cv::VideoCapture input;
  input.open(CV_CAP_OPENNI_ASUS);

  if(!input.isOpened())
    {
      std::cout << "Error.\n";
      return -1;
    }
}
```

I'm using OpenCV2, installed with the JetPack. I installed OpenNI2 following instructions [here](http://myzharbot.robot-home.it/blog/software/configuration-nvidia-jetson-tk1/asus-xtion-pro-live-openni2-compilation-install-instructions/) (built from source). I can run SimpleViewer and other programs just fine, so the Asus is communicating. Following Tutorial 2 [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/learn/tutorials), I am able to load a video image in an OpenCV program from a file, but not read the Asus. Running `lsusb` shows that the device is active:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1d27:0601 ASUS
```

I *have* successfully read from the Asus from within ROS.

I have seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22443311/can-not-grab-image-from-videocapture-opencv-with-asus-xtion-pro-live/29042678?noredirect=1#comment46328594_29042678), but it does not help (I did incorporate the `_ASUS` for the open macro).

[UPDATE] I have since loaded openNI2 and OpenCV3 on an ubuntu laptop (14.04). Again, SimpleViewer works fine. The built in camera works fine (with `input.open(0)` to access the default camera). The only thing that doesn't work is reading the Asus from within an OpenCV program.

:grumble:

Does anyone have suggestions for what to try next? I'm sure I'm missing something obvious -- any debugging help appreciated.

Comment: maybe it takes a while for the sensor to initialise ?
Can you try something like this:```int main()
{
  cv::Mat image0,image0Show;

  cv::VideoCapture input;
  input.open(CV_CAP_OPENNI_ASUS);

  while(true){


   if( !input.grab() ){
        cout << "can not grab images." << endl;
        return -1;
    }else if( input.retrieve( image0, CV_CAP_OPENNI_DEPTH_MAP ) ){
     image0.convertTo( image0Show, CV_8UC1, 0.05f);
     imshow("image0",image0Show);
    } 


   if(waitKey(30) == 27) break;//press ESC to exit
  }

}``` ?

Comment: Thanks. I modified your code (to remove the `return -1` so that it just retries) and it neither grabs an image nor retrieves the depth map.

Comment: [Sorry - I can't edit the previous reply.] I'm going to try everything out on a different computer to see if I'm doing something wrong, or if my sensor is (unlikely) malfunctioning. My goal for the moment is just learning OpenCV, but eventually I have to run it on the Jetson, so any other ideas are appreciated.